# Returning variable name C++

Tags: c++, macros

I use this code

```
#define _(x) cout << #x;
```

as macro, at the beginning of the program, to return a variable name. It functions well in main, but not at all when nested in other funcions. For example if a define

```
void print (int p)
{
   _(p); cout << "=" << p;
}

int main()
{
   int a=1, b=2;
   _(a); 
   cout << " = " << a;
   print(b);
}
```

the output will be
    a = 1
    p = 2

Any idea to overcome this?

Comment: but that's exactly what to expect. Your first variable is named `a`, the second is named `p`

Comment: Why? Why> Why is one interested in the name of the variable name?

Comment: He is expecting a b=2 on the output but it doesn't work because his macro is made to spit out the variable name which changes according to the scope that he is operating in.  In your sub functions the compiler considers the name of the variable to be the local scope variable name and will connect those compile symbols on linking to higher levels of the scope.  The only way that I can think of to store the name of the variable is to call your macro from the same scope and then hand it into a class constructor or other function to maintain the varaible.

Comment: @Wug - A debugger is easier and works.

Comment: Very poor naming conventions: macro name does not describe its purpose; identifier starts with an underscore '_'; no comments as to the purpose or use of the macro.

Answer (score 4):

```
#define _(x) cout << #x;
#define print(v) _(v); cout << "=" << v;
```

The reason it's not behaving the way you expect is when you call it from inside your function, the variable's name is "p".  So it's doing exactly what you told it, even if it's not what you meant.

Comment: This will work if the asker truly only needs to print from any sub function.  Not that it's a bad Idea if that is the case, but if the asker has a variety of things that he want to accomplish from multiple sub-functions, he would have to provide a macro for each, and that would also destroy the capacity for recursion as well as make the size of his executable very large depending on how many times he needs to call his function.

Comment: Yes, thanks very much. This was the outcome i desired, I understood what was the problem, mayble i didn't express myself well, but i didn't had a clue on what to do.

Comment: I'm only doing some exercises to improve in c++. I understand it's something a little out of the flow.

Comment: @user1507571 : A good place to start in improving in C++ is to _avoid_ macros. ;-]

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be working correctly.  The values of `a` and `p` are `1` and `2`, respectively, which is exactly what your output shows.  What output are you expecting?

If you're expecting the second output to be `b = 2`, then I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of the language.  The function has no knowledge of the variable name that the calling function used (if it used a variable at all) when calling it.  Higher-level languages with pervasive introspection capabilities might be able to do something like this, but C++ can't.

Perhaps more importantly, what do you gain by knowing the name of the variable that you don't already know by looking at the code or running the code in a basic debugger?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to pass the info into the print function somehow.

```
struct named {
    int &x_;
    const char *n_;
    operator int () const { return x_; }
    named(int &x, const char *n) : x_(x), n_(n) {}
};

const char * name (int, const char *s) { return s; }
const char * name (named &n, const char *s) { return n.n_; }

#define _(x) std::cout << name(x, #x)

void print (named p) {
    _(p); std::cout << " = " << p << std::endl;
}
#define print(x) print(named(x, #x))

int main() {
   int a=1, b=2;
   _(a); std::cout << " = " << a << std::endl;
   print(b);
}
```

Comment: I'm gratefull to you all, I understood a lot of things. Like I said, I'm only doing some exercises. I defined a class of points, and needed to "print" the points in this format "P(x,y)". I thought this was a good idea to make the program shorter and more readable, instead of, for every point writing
    _(P); cout << '('<<p.get_x()<<','<<p.get_y()<< ')';
I could instead write
    print(P)

Comment: @user1507571: But it sounds like Wug's solution is what you actually want: make `print` a macro.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the name of the variable to be part of the variable itself. C++ does not give variables names at runtime. The identifiers you use in the program refer only to the values getting passed around.

You can define an object type that explicitly includes a name:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template< typename t >
struct named_value {
    t value;
    std::string name;
};

template< typename t >
void _( named_value< t > const &nv ) { // not a good name for a function
    std::cout << nv.name; // not a good semantic for a function
}

template< typename t >
std::ostream &operator<< ( std::ostream &s, named_value< t > const &v ) {
    return s << v.value;
}

typedef named_value< int > named_int;

void print (named_int p)
{
   _(p); std::cout << "=" << p;
}

int main()
{
   named_int a = { 1, "a" }, b = { 2, "b" };
   _(a); 
   std::cout << " = " << a;
   print(b);
}
```

http://ideone.com/AFHEq

**BUT,** you really shouldn't write programs like this.

Comment: Call me old fashioned, I use templates for last resort. i.e. want a family of classes that have similar properties - like stacks, queues

Comment: @EdHeal There's no reason to think he only wants to name his `int`s. Is there an advantage to avoiding the template here?

Comment: @EdHeal Because defining a separate class for every case would accomplish that. Thanks for the laugh.

Comment: You could do that - but that is not I am advocating. You are simply not doing this. One thinks that the thing you care about is your job security.

Comment: @EdHeal LOL, you downvoted because the template was too hard to read. Job security indeed. :D

Comment: … well, the really amusing part is that you seem to take the *rest* of the question and answer seriously. No, I have better things to do with my time.